# Offset function for dynamic range not ignoring cells with #N/A in Line Chart

Tags: excel, dynamic, offset

I am facing an issue with excel offset function for a range which increases horizontally and vertically. 
I have a pivot table built from raw data which keeps on updating. I am mainly concerned with products and corresponding price per quarter in the pivot.
I have created another sheet pulling the products from the pivot and corresponding blended price (calculated based on pivot values - Sales/Units).

Below is the code:

Formula to pull the products from the pivot:

IFERROR(INDEX($A$10:$A$155, AGGREGATE(15,3,ROW($A$10:$A$155)-ROW($A$9)/($A$10:$A$155<>""),ROWS($A$10:A10))),#N/A)

Formula to display the corresponding blended price for the product:

IFERROR(INDEX(AZ$10:AZ$155, MATCH($CC10,$A$10:$A$155,0)),#N/A)

Now I need to create a line chart for the above data. Below is the code for Name Manager:

Quarters=OFFSET('Blended Price Calculation'!$CD$9,0,0,1,COUNTA('Blended Price Calculation'!$CC$9:$DA$9)-1)

0.45_Saline=OFFSET('Blended Price Calculation'!$CD$10,0,0,1,COUNTA('Blended Price Calculation'!$CC$10:$DA$10)-1)

0.9_Saline=OFFSET('Blended Price Calculation'!$CD$11,0,0,1,COUNTA('Blended Price Calculation'!$CC$11:$DA$11)-1)

10_Dextrose=OFFSET('Blended Price Calculation'!$CD$12,0,0,1,COUNTA('Blended Price Calculation'!$CC$12:$DA$12)-1)

Similarly for the rest of the products

I want to the horizontal axis to be Quarters and not Products.

Dashboard - Filter based on Slicer
[image: Dashboard]

Original Excel without filter
[image: Excel 1]

Excel when Slicer filter is applied (to display only 2 products)
[image: Excel]

Problem:
The chart displays #N/A when I filter data using Slicer in the dashboard. Slicer is acting on pivot table. Basically I need help on offset function which will pick only those values which has data for both rows and columns. Currently I have the formula working for Columns but it is not working for rows, hence the line chart is considering all the rows. But since I have selected only a couple of products (using slicer) out of 100 odd products, line chart shows graph perfectly for those selected products and shows #N/A for the rest.

How can I not display #N/A in my chart legend? I think having a combination of vertical and horizontal offset function should solve my problem but I am struggling to find the solution.

Any help is really appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: How do you filter the data? Why do you use range names with OFFSET()? Why don't you just click a cell in the data and insert a line chart? Then you can use the Auto Filter to show only some rows and there will be no NA in the legend.

Comment: Again: how do you filter the data? Is this a pivot table or a regular table? Do the slicers act on the data in your first screenshot? Or not? Why are the cells in the second screenshot showing #NA? Do they not have the source numbers? Do they have formulas? If so, what are the formulas? Please understand that we can't help if you don't show us the data architecture and all formulas.

Comment: Please do not post info in comments. Please edit your question and post any information about clarifying into the question. Then post a comment to alert the followers of the question.

Comment: You should really take the [tour] and learn [ask]. Then go back and edit your question so it is possible to understand your scenario without playing the game of "20 Questions". You are not doing yourself any favours by not revealing your whole setup. I am frankly getting tired of repeatedly asking how your scenario works.

Comment: @teylyn: I have updated my Question. Let me know if it is clearer now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you have hard-wired ten series into the chart. You can use range names to dynamically change the number of data points in a series, but you can't use a formula approach to dynamically change the number of series in a regular Excel chart. That will require VBA.

If you use a pivot chart instead, you can select the series with a slicer and the legend will show only the visible series.

Edit: Here is a screenshot to illustrate how a pivot chart can be filtered and unused series will not show in the legend.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Teylyn. But I didn’t get what exactly you are trying to say in the second portion of your comment.

Comment: I'm saying that you may want to use a pivot chart if you want to show or hide series dynamically without having the legend show NA. I added a screenshot to my answer.

Comment: I used another pivot and the result is as per expectation. Thank you Teylyn.